# AS3 - How do I stop a function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function in my "enterFrameHandler* function and it is structured like this:

```
private function addBoss():void{
   if(kills >= 3){
     trace("boss time");
   }
}
```

Since "addBoss" is a part of my ENTER_FRAME event listener function, "boss time" is traced infinitely as soon as kills reaches 3. I would like this function to stop as soon as it activates 1 time.

Is there another event listener I could use that will check for the function, but then stop as soon as it goes off?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to handle this in the part of your script where you add to kills instead of checking it every frame.

Comment: You can have more than one listener/handler for the ENTER_FRAME event.  use a seperate one for your addBoss and then remove it as one of the answers says when your condition is met.  This is more efficient than the answer that wants to keep checking every frame if it's boss time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private function addBoss():void{
    if(kills >= 3){
       trace("boss time");
       removeBossEnterFrame();
   }
}
private function removeBossEnterFrame():void{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addBoss);
}
```

I'd prob remove the Enterframe event listner thats calling the addBoss function once you trace out "boss time".

Comment: `addBoss()` is part of his enter frame function, it's not the only thing running, as he mentioned.

Comment: It's perfectly legit to have multiple eventlisteners listening for the same event, so the code could be split between 2 methods.

Comment: @xLite ahh woops. Yeah, agree with Will Kru, otherwise xLite's answer works fine as well I guess. Personally I like to keep separate functions for each thing (addBoss() being a thing), so its easier to clean up listeners and keep track of whats running. End of the day its up to OP and whatever seems easier/more familiar I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
private var isBossTime:Boolean = false;

private function addBoss():void
{
    if(kills >= 3 && isBossTime == false)
    {
        trace("boss time");

        isBossTime = true;
    }
}
```